# Select just thumbnails from user's youtube subscriptions

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I use `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2&access_token=$access_token']&alt=json` to get the new subscription videos from the user's feed. How can I (if it's even possible) select just thumbnails?

Answer (score 0):

Add `fields=entry(media:group(media:thumbnail(@url)))` to your API call url. More about this, here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial#Fields_Formatting_Rules